# Para que serve o operador "~*" em um select no SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Vi essa linha de código em alguns exemplos:

```
SELECT * from produto where nome ~*'$texto_pesquisado';"
```

Mas não sei qual a função do `~*`, não achei nenhuma explicação. Para que ele serve?

Answer (score 3):

O `~*` é um operador de regex do PostgreSQL que não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas, como pode ver na [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

Então, no seu exemplo, você está buscando um nome que tanto faz que comece como maiúsculo ou minúsculo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 2):

No PostgreSQL o operador `~*` serve para buscar expressões regulares contendo a string passada como parâmetro de busca, sem fazer diferenciação de caracteres maiúsculos e minúsculos, ou seja, no case sensitive.

No caso, essa sua query `SELECT * from produto where nome ~*'$texto_pesquisado';"`, vai retornar todas as linhas que contiverem a em seu nome a expressão `'$texto_pesquisado'`, não importa se esteja maiúscula ou minuscula.

Você pode ver mais sobre aqui https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.